# Why do we use keys in multipart/formdata in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, multipartform-data, angular2-services

What is the role of companyName and companyCode?

```
const formData: any = new FormData();

formData.append('companyName', companyName);
formData.append('companyCode', companyCode);
formData.append('aboutCompany', aboutCompany);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4526273/2641752 Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you are trying to create a form data to post from a form, so first create a new form data object by `const formData: any = new FormData();` and you are adding following information(companyName, companyCode, aboutCompany) to that form data with a key of the same name. at the end formData will be have something as below:

```
formData = {
 'companyName', companyName,
 'companyCode', companyCode,
 'aboutCompany', aboutCompany
 }
```